# Selectively dumping data with mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I am trying to export my database using mysqldump and the sql file should satisfy the following conditions

1. The file should not contain data from table_x ( Keep the structure )
2. Delete/skip data that
   is older than 10 days from table_y ( Keep the structure )

The conditions may increase in future for different tables.

This dump file will be used on local environment and will work as replacement for production database.

And Is there a way to write all these conditions inside a file?

Comment: sorry , do you want , to write some batch file to do this ?what os you using?

Comment: Yes ideally or just a mysqldump statement

Comment: @uma I am using linux ubuntu

Comment: sorry for I am not idea about your 1,2 point. I think you want to take sql back up ,file. I think do you can more explain , what you want to do, really some one answer you.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqldump` is what you want: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --host=localhost --user=MyUser --password=MyPassword MyDatabase MyTable --where="mydatefield > 'insert-10 day old date here'"
mysqldump --single-transaction --host=localhost --user=MyUser --password=MyPassword --ignore-table=MyDatabase.MyTable --ignore-tableMyDatabase.MySecondIgnoredTable
```

This answer could be improved by changing the 'insert-10 day old date here' placeholder with a backtick bash command that is curdate - 10 days.

Specifying the password on the command line can be a security risk and is discouraged, especially in scripts or shared hosting environment. Check the help file above to see the more complex process of creating a credentials file to use in the command.

If you have MyISAM tables instead of InnoDB you'll want to switch --single-transaction with --skip-add-locks

I realize this question is from a year ago, but someone might still find useful.